# Finding SERVER_IFACE for dhcprelay in busybox

Tags: networking, routing, dhcp, busybox

I'm working on a busybox image that will provide (along with other services) a dhcp relay in an isolated virtual environment.  The config file I'll be given has the client interface (ie. eth1) and the server address (ie. 192.168.100.100).  The busybox dhcprelay implementation, however, also requires the interface on which the dhcp server can be accessed

```
# dhcprelay --help
BusyBox v1.22.1 (2016-11-12 03:36:30 MSK) multi-call binary.

Usage: dhcprelay CLIENT_IFACE[,CLIENT_IFACE2]... SERVER_IFACE [SERVER_IP]

Relay DHCP requests between clients and server
```

What's the easiest way, given the server address, to determine the apropriate interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your system has the `ip route` command, you can lookup what route the network will take out of the machine for a given ip. Eg

```
$ ip route get 8.8.8.8    
8.8.8.8 via 192.168.0.254 dev p4p1  src 192.168.0.20 
cache
```

This replies interface `p4p1` and gateway `192.168.0.254` will be used.